# How do we name the property of a map that it preserve the membership relation of the set and its subset?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Given a set $A$ and its one particular subset $B$, a map $f$ that has the property that it does change the membership relation of the subset, namely,

$f(x)\in f(B)$ if $x\in B$, $f(x)\notin f(B)$ if $x\notin B$.

I want to focus on such map. Is there a specialized phrase for this? Any textbook or link I can refer to would be helpful too. Thank you!

Comment: Is the property for a particular subset $B$, or for all subsets $B$?

Comment: Just for a particular subset $B$.

Comment: I am not familiar with any particular name. It holds if and only if $f(B)\cap f(A\setminus B) = \varnothing$.

Comment: This is already a more compact (and better!) way for me refer to this property. Thank you Arturo!